# Suspended user last seen today?

Tags: support, account-suspension, last-activity

I recently ended up on "[He who shall not be named](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5640/geoffrey-chetwood)"s profile.  The suspension said it ended in about 2 weeks, but the "Last seen" field said "yesterday".  I just thought it was stuck at the value it was at when the user was suspended, but then I looked at the profile again today, and it says "last seen: 6 hours ago".  What gives?

Comment: Why should this user not be named?  Did I miss something?

Comment: @jzd, he was a very controversial user a long time ago, but received a long suspension, so only the oldest of the MSO old folks remember him now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing unusual. When you're [in the box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) the following are applied:

> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.

But you can still log in and go about your business of notching up a fresh **seen** timestamp.

You just can't interact until the timed suspension ends.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  For some reason I seemed to think suspension meant no logging in at all.